# Issues with Memory Cache. TryGetValue returns false

Tags: c#, .net-core

**In this code snippet i simply put null in MemoryCache and then check if this key exists:**

```
        var _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
        _cache.Set<string>(cacheKey, null);
        var isInCache = _cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out string nothing);
```

isInCache is false in this case. Is this behavior expected?

I use .NET Core 2.2 Console app.

Comment: Late to the party, but I'm dealing with compiler suggestions and ran into this post. I'm on .Net 7 and TryGetValue wants to return a nullable TItem. Since you are defining your return not with string? but with string.... I wonder if that's your problem.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Based on the [source code](https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs#L27) for `TryGetValue()` it will return `false` if null is returned when it checks type `if (result is TItem item)`. However, the `.Count` property would return 1. (thanks to @jgoday comment for these details).

An alternative is to have a 'null value' (e.g. `Guid.NewGuid()`) that you can use to represent a null value, this way something is entered into the cache so you can verify whether it has ever been added.

```
public class MyCache
{
  private MemoryCache _cache = new MemoryCache(new MemoryCacheOptions());
  private string nullValue = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

  public void Set(string cacheKey, string toSet)
    => _cache.Set<string>(cacheKey, toSet == null ? nullValue : toSet);

  public string Get(string cacheKey)
  {
    var isInCache = _cache.TryGetValue(cacheKey, out string cachedVal);
    if (!isInCache) return null;

    return cachedVal == nullValue ? null : cachedVal;
  }
}
```

Comment: Documentation is not for the `Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory` assembly the OP is using.

Comment: In dotnet.core is not really documented, but based on the source code (https://github.com/aspnet/Caching/blob/master/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Abstractions/MemoryCacheExtensions.cs), TryGetValue extension would never return true if a value is null ( null is Titem always false), however Count property will return 1. It seems like a little inconsistency ...

Comment: Sorry for incorrect link. Updated with details from @jgoday